# How to insert array elements into db only if they do not already exist

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, node-mysql

Here is my db schema:

```
CREATE TABLE technologies (
    technologyName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE videos (
    videoId             INT          NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    title               VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
    url                 VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
    description         VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
    channelName         VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE technology_video_map (
    videoId        INT,
    technologyName VARCHAR(50),

    PRIMARY KEY (videoId, technologyName),
    FOREIGN KEY (videoId) REFERENCES videos(videoId),
    FOREIGN KEY (technologyName) REFERENCES technologies(technologyName)
);
```

I want the user to submit a video:

```
var input = {
  title: 'Grunt makes your web development better!',
  url: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TMKj0BxzVgw',
  description: 'If you\'re not using a task runner/build system like Grunt or Gulp...',
  channelName: 'LearnCode.academy',
  technologies: ['Grunt', 'JavaScript']
};
```

And I want to insert it into the db. Inserting *only* the video is easy enough for me:

```
var technologies = input.technologies; // save for later
delete input.technologies;
connection.query('INSERT INTO videos SET ?', input, function (err, result) {
    var videoId = result.insertId;
});
```

(`connection` comes from the brilliant [node-mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql))

What I am having trouble with, is inserting the technologies into the db. I have identified that the first step is:

1. Insert elements in `input.technologies` into the `technologies` table if they do not already exist.

I can only imagine doing this using a `for` loop or something which is yucky.

The second step, I think, is:

2. Insert a new record into the junction table, `technology_video_map` from the `connection.query` callback, as we need the `videoId`.

Again, I cannot imagine an idiomatic way to do this using SQL. Can someone please guide me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use INSERT IGNORE and join your input.technologies array. This will insert records that do not exist and will ignore records that already exist

```
var query = "INSERT IGNORE INTO technologies (technologyName) VALUES ('" + input.technologies.join("'),('") + "')";
```

Comment: I never knew that existed.  Thanks.

Comment: I didn't know about `insert ignore`, so thank you for that. Is this not vulnerable to SQL injection? If yes, how do I prevent against SQL injection in this case?

Comment: insert ignore itself is not vulnerable to SQL injection. node-mysql already performs escaping if you're putting your query into `connection.query('SELECT blah FROM blahblah WHERE blah = ? ', myString, function (err, result){})` . You can also escape input.technologies directly. See this link for more details https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#escaping-query-values

Answer (score 0):

You have to check for its existence

```
if not exists(select technologyName from technoligies 
              where technologyName='$technologies')
insert (..)
```

If you are not using a stored procedure, then fire a query to fetch it. If it fails, then insert it.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "IF NOT EXISTS" without the exclamation?